# rolling two dice: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, dice

I'm trying to implement a function that takes two dices as input and computes two values.

The first value is the number of times the first dice wins (out of all possible 36 choices), the second value is the number of times the second dice wins.

Here is my code:

```
def count_wins(dice1, dice2):
  assert len(dice1) == 6 and len(dice2) == 6
  dice1_wins, dice2_wins = 0, 0

# write your code here
dice1 = input('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6')
dice2 = input('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6')
def roll_dice():
  return(random.randint(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),random.randint(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
for i in range(36):
  dice1, dice2 = roll_dice()
  if dice1 > dice2:
    dice1_wins+=1
  if dice2 > dice1:
    dice2_wins+=1
  if dice2 == dice1:
    pass
return (dice1_wins, dice2_wins)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error on line 17:
    return (dice1_wins, dice2_wins)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: Looks like your indentation is messed up. Is all of this code supposed to be part of the `count_wins` function? Because as indented, only the first two lines are in `count_wins`, one line is in `roll_dice`, and the rest are at the top level. You'd need to add extra indentation to every line from `dice1 = input(...)` to the end matching the indentation of `dice1_wins, dice2_wins = 0, 0`.

Comment: i see.... lemme try to fix the indentations first

Answer (score 1):

I tried to fix the indentation for you, Try the below code:

```
import random

def count_wins():
    dice1_wins, dice2_wins = 0, 0
    for i in range(0,36):
      dice1, dice2 = roll_dice()
      if dice1 > dice2:
        dice1_wins+=1
      if dice2 > dice1:
        dice2_wins+=1
      if dice2 == dice1:
        pass
    return (dice1_wins, dice2_wins)


def roll_dice():
  return(random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6))#returns random numbers between 1 to 6.

print (count_wins())#Calls the method count_wins and prints the required output.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i think it does work. but may I ask how will I print out the output though?

Comment: @ShirleyDong I have changed the answer in order to print the output. Please check the answer if it solved your query. :)

Comment: Thanks! but somehow I received this?? Error on line 23:
    print count_wins([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6])
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ShirleyDong I guess you are using python 3+. I have updated it to make it backwards compatible you can check it here https://repl.it/repls/DeadSuspiciousTransversals

Comment: I think you made a typo on the last line. it should be print (count_wins([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6])). However, I got this( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) as output? although i'm trying to print (number of dice1 wins, number of dice2 wins). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import  randint


dice1 = [1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 8]

dice2 = [2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9]


def count_wins():
dice1_wins, dice2_wins = 0, 0
for i in range(0,36):
  dice1, dice2 = roll_dice()
  if dice1 > dice2:
    dice1_wins+=1
  if dice2 > dice1:
    dice2_wins+=1
  if dice2 == dice1:
    pass
return dice1_wins, dice2_wins


def roll_dice():
  return(randint(1,6),randint(1,6))#returns random numbers between 1 to 6.
print (count_wins())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some description to say how you solved the problem.

Comment: I just solved the indentation problem and improved the solution given above . By just a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint, seed
from datetime import datetime

seed(datetime.now())

dice1=[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
dice2=[1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6]

num_rounds = 36

assert len(dice1) == 6 and len(dice2) == 6

num_dice1_wins = 0
num_dice2_wins = 0

for _ in range(num_rounds):
    dice1_result = dice1[randint(0, 5)]
    dice2_result = dice2[randint(0, 5)]

    if dice1_result > dice2_result:
            num_dice1_wins += 1
    elif dice2_result > dice1_result:
            num_dice2_wins += 1

if num_dice1_wins > num_dice2_wins:
        print("  ({} , {} ) ".format(   num_dice1_wins,num_dice2_wins))
```

Comment: Please properly format the code, and perhaps describe how it's different from the other answers.